# Changing a PSN account on PS3

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus

I just bought a used Playstation 3. I am going to change the PSN account (create a new one) but I have a few questions before doing so.

1. My brother already started playing a game and he does not want to
   lose his save file. Can it be preserved? If so how?
2. If the original owner had bought some DLC from his account and I do not delete the
   account (keep both accounts on the machine) can I use that dlc? I
   mean can I install it from his account and use them from my account?
3. Also the original account was a US PSN account, I am going to create
   a UK PSN account. Does any of the answers change given that fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One*: You can back up save files and then restore them at a later time even to another account. If you are a PS+ member you can back them up to a server and they will be linked to your PSN. However in your case, you'll probably want to back them up manually, which can be done as so:

> 1. On the XMB (cross media bar), go to the Game section.
> 2. Go to Game Saves
> 3. Put in your memory stick (cf, ms duo, sd)
> 4. Find the game save you want to copy/backup, highlight it and hit the Triangle button.
> 5. Choose the menu option to Copy
> 6. Hit the X button on the memory stick and let it copy.

Source: [PS3 : How to backup PS3 game save files to memory stick / sd / cf](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2570/ps3_how_to_backup_ps3_game_save_files/)

*It should be noted that some games use copy-prevention methods to, well, prevent copying. However, it's still possible to back even those games up. Google is your friend here.*

*Two:* I'm surprised the previous owner's PSN is still on there, but yes you could use his DLC, as long as his PSN remains registered on the console (so don't delete his User account.) Off the top of my head I don't know how this will affect trophies. You should still be able to earn DLC trophies, but they *might* register for the owner of the original purchase. (*The PS Vita has this problem.*)

*Three:* The PS3 is not region locked for games, so you should be able to play everything fine. However, I do believe the Playstation Store is region based, and so some content will only be available depending on which region's store you access. I'm not sure if this is determined by the console (e.g. a US PS3 vs. a JP PS3) or registered PSN region. Also, you *may* have some conflict if trying to purchase content that is normally not available in your region.

I hope this helps!

*P.S. Congrats on the new PS3!*

Comment: The Vita is a single-user platform, which is why it has the trophy problem. The PS3 allows multiple users and each will have his own trophies, regardless of which account owns the game being played.

Comment: Also, what you can download (which regional store you use) is determined by the account. You can have, e.g., a US and a JP PSN account on the same machine, each will use its own shop, but each can play games downloaded by the other.